# Browserslist Error on Angular Build

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 app that recently started having issues on our build server. The Angular version is `^4.4.6` and the CLI version is `1.5.5`. Up until this week, there were no issues building the application on the build server, and we did not change any package versions. This build error occurs while a Docker image is being built on the build server. The application also builds just fine on my local machine. Here's an output of the errors, along with related package versions:

[image]

The raw output is:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-3!./src/styles.scss
Module build failed: 
@include caret;
        ^
    No mixin named caret
    in /usr/src/app/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_dropdown.scss (line 11, column 12)
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/material-design-iconic-font/dist/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Write any browsers query (for instance, `defaults`) before `not ie <= 11`
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:139:15
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:132:18)
    at browserslist (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:224:16)
    at Browsers.parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:61:16)
    at new Browsers (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:52:30)
    at loadPrefixes (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:70:24)
    at plugin (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:81:24)
    at LazyResult.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:197:27
    at <anonymous>
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Write any browsers query (for instance, `defaults`) before `not ie <= 11`
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:139:15
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:132:18)
    at browserslist (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:224:16)
    at Browsers.parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:61:16)
    at new Browsers (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:52:30)
    at loadPrefixes (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:70:24)
    at plugin (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:81:24)
    at LazyResult.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:197:27
    at <anonymous>
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Write any browsers query (for instance, `defaults`) before `not ie <= 11`
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:139:15
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:132:18)
    at browserslist (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:224:16)
    at Browsers.parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:61:16)
    at new Browsers (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:52:30)
    at loadPrefixes (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:70:24)
    at plugin (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:81:24)
    at LazyResult.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:197:27
    at <anonymous>
ERROR in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Write any browsers query (for instance, `defaults`) before `not ie <= 11`
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:139:15
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolve (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:132:18)
    at browserslist (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:224:16)
    at Browsers.parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:61:16)
    at new Browsers (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:52:30)
    at loadPrefixes (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:70:24)
    at plugin (/usr/src/app/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:81:24)
    at LazyResult.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:277:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:192:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:197:27
    at <anonymous>
```

The frustrating thing is that locally I've checked the version of bootstrap and what's installed in the `node_modules` folder, for example, and the file that it references, `_dropdown.scss` isn't trying to use a mixin called `caret` at all.

Again, I'm not seeing these issues when building for any environment locally, only on the build server, inside a TeamCity container. I've tried changing the `package.json` to install specific versions of packages as well, but to no avail.

Is there a way to debug this and determine exactly what version of the packages are being installed and how to fix the errors?

### Edit

I added up above the note that this error happens while I'm building a Docker image for this app. The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM johnpapa/angular-cli as angular-build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
# RUN npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'
COPY . .
RUN ng build --env=test

FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="Preston Lamb"
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=angular-build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Comment: To check the package versions, you'd need to look on the build server. If you open the `node_modules` directory, you can  open the `package.json` within the subdir you're interested in , and check the `version` property

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this: This is output during the building of a docker image that will run the Angular app. So nothing is preserved as far as the `node_modules` directory is concerned once the error occurs and the build is canceled.

Comment: On your machine, if you do `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install && ng build` does it still work? I am wondering if you have stale artifacts on your machine, which may be why you don't see what is happening on the server. 

Also, is the build OS the same as your own?

Comment: Yes, I've tried completely removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling (even cloned the repo a second time in a different location just to make sure) and the build still works locally. macOS 10.13.5 locally, and this is building in TeamCity (run with Docker) on a Linux (Debian 9.2) box for the build server.

Comment: One thing you could try, to narrow it down... remove all of the carets from your package.json. Then try it to see if the build server works. It sounds like you may have had a bad release on a minor (in)direct dependency. Try that and commit it and see what happens. I don't like to blind commit ideally, but your scenario is less than ideal so it seems ok to suggest.

Comment: If the problem is an indirect rolling minor version dependency... then... that sucks. Unless you are using package-lock.json, it will take time to figure out.

Comment: I will be honest, it makes no sense that this would happen during the docker image build. This has nothing to do with the image build.

Comment: @frosty I agree with all your comments haha It doesn't make sense. We are using package-lock.json, it doesn't happen locally, but does here. I can build the Docker image locally and push it to our repository, then run the application just fine, but obviously I can't do that all the time. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thanks for the suggestions, I'm gonna try removing all the carets from package.json to see if that works. I've tried it on a couple, but just one at a time.

Comment: @frosty removing all carets and tildes from the package.json seems to have worked. Thanks for the idea! I don't know if you want to add it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can try is to remove all of the carets from your `package.json`. If any of your deps had a minor version that broke you, fixing the versioning will get you past this minor revision issues. But, you will eventually need to go back and find out which dep caused the issue. It may take some time. I would suggest divide and conquer. Add half of the carets back in. If the error comes back, it was one of them. And keep going half and half until you find which one it was. If it was more than one, then your life will suck.

Best of luck! Cheers Preston!